# Using an array inside array

Tags: angularjs, jsonschema, angular-schema-form

I'm trying to generate a form which will have multiple vehicles and each vehicle should have multiple people inside it.

I tried to do it by using an array inside another array. But for some obscure reasons it's not working.

This is what I want:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmxF3.png

This is what I have (so far):

**Form:**

```
[
  {
    "key": "vehicles",
    "items": [
      "['vehicles'][]['plate-number']",
      "['vehicles'][]['color']",
      {
        "key": "people",
        "items": [
            "['vehicles'][]['people'][]['name']"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Schema:**

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "vehicles": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "plate-number": {
            "title": "Plate number",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "color": {
            "title": "Color",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "people": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "enum": ["dr","jr","sir","mrs","mr","NaN","dj"]
                },
                "name": {
                  "title": "Name",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
stefankmitph's answer solvers my problem. Thank you!

But something weird is happening: a new object `person` is added at the same level of `vehicles`. Also, when I fill a person's information and then delete this person the models is not updated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  What is not working?

Comment: Could you show the code that generates that?

Comment: can you post please, what html code you tried till now?

Comment: @BrennoMartins you edited **stefankmitph's answer solvers my problem**, then you should accept that answer so that it will help other users with same problem like you faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema you provide does not add a property 'gender' (as shown in your picture link). So I took 'title' instead of 'gender':

```
[
  {
    "key": "vehicles",
    "items": [
      "vehicles[].plate-number",
      "vehicles[].color", {
          "key": "people",
          "type": "array",
          "title": "People",
          "items": [
              "vehicles[].people[].name",
              "vehicles[].people[].title"
              ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I hope this is what you're looking for!
Note: Tested with [Schema Form Example Page](http://textalk.github.io/angular-schema-form/examples/bootstrap-example.html)